# Threejs sprite ordering

Tags: three.js, voxel

I'm having an issue rendering sprites using Three.js, to complicate the issue further I'm using a game engine [voxel.js](http://voxeljs.com) to manage the instance.

Example: http://christopherdebeer.com/sandbox/voxeljs/

I've tried messing with depth{write|test}:

```
material = new game.THREE.SpriteMaterial({
  map: spriteB, 
  useScreenCoordinates: false,
  alignment: game.THREE.SpriteAlignment.bottomCenter,
  color: 0xffffff,
  fog: true,
  depthWrite: true,
  depthTest: false
});
```

for the semi transparent meshes on the left of the example.

What I need is a transparent mesh or voxel to give a volume of space some substance while displaying a 2d sprite at that position.

How can I solve this issue, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost exactly a year after you needed it, but @WestLangley described how sprites are rendered last and thus do not play well with transparent objects. He provides some tips on working around this.

[three.js - cannot view a sprite through a mesh with transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046972/three-js-cannot-view-a-sprite-through-a-mesh-with-transparency)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an alpha test missing to me: try to add the parameter `alphaTest: 0.5` to the parameters you pass to the SpriteMaterial and see if it helps (try with `depthTest`set to  `true`)