# three.js - cannot view a sprite through a mesh with transparency?

Tags: text, three.js, transparency, sprite

I have a group of sprites, as well as some other meshes, and in front of them I've printed some text as a texture on a mesh. Everything is viewable through the text, except for the sprites which disappear whenever the text's tranparency is printed over them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sprites are rendered last, so they will not work well with other transparent objects.

Your work-around is to set

```
renderer.autoClear = false;
```

and then to place the transparent text into `scene2`, and implement two render passes like so:

```
renderer.render( scene, camera );
renderer.clearDepth(); // optional, depending on use case
renderer.render( scene2, camera );
```

three.js r.68

Comment: Sounds like just what I need! I'll check and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: Referencing this example: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html
Don't forget to manually clear:

 "renderer.clear();
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
 renderer.clearDepth();
 renderer.render(scene2, camera);"