# Three.js - transparent planes hiding sprites

Tags: three.js, sprite, transparency

When we add text-spites on scene, we saw that our transparent planes hide sprites, but didn't hide any 3d Objects. 
**Why is this and how to make sprites visible under transparent planes?**

To look [PNG example click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htrIk.png)

My plane is:

```
// transparent plane
geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 200, 200);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xa6cfe2,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            transparent: true,
            opacity: 0.5,
            depthFunc: THREE.LessDepth,
        });
```

But it seems no work good.
So, for that examle i wrote some code on fiddle, to figure out the problem:
[look fidddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vyLc6roq/1/)

Comment: also i check Stack and find example with sprites (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046972/three-js-cannot-view-a-sprite-through-a-mesh-with-transparency) but i thing it wouldn't be good for my project (link to it https://github.com/VKIU/ProgressTracking) because: 
- we have over 15+ sprites, which we must position over axis;
- we change camera positions like camera.set(x,y,z), and if we will make 2 cameras and 2 scenes (for sprites and for another) we must send all positions from first scene to second scene (that 15 sprites + rotation...)

Answer (score 2):

three.js renders opaque objects first, then transparent objects.

You can use this pattern to prevent your transparent objects from writing to the depth buffer:

```
// transparent plane
geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 1, 1 );

material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    color: 0xa6cfe2,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5,
    depthWrite: false
} );
```

three.js r.112

Comment: this not that i want to get help with, i just need to draw sprite under transparent plane and save it visible like it "under transparent plane", not behind plane. Like red cube.

Comment: Awesome!!! This solved a problem that I'd almost given up on. Thanks!